# Android ignoring Style XML Background instruction

Tags: android, xml, android-styles

I want to create an orange button style which I placed my style.xml file as follows:

```
<style name="Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
<style name="Button.OrangeButton">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@drawable/orange_button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>

</style>
```

I then assign the style to a Button as follows:

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start Broadcast"
    android:id="@+id/start_broadcast_button"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:theme="@style/Button.OrangeButton"

    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    />
```

However the styling instruction is not passed on to the button - it retains the default button format.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
android:theme="@style/Button.OrangeButton"
```

to

```
style="@style/Button.OrangeButton"
```

Comment: Correct! Thanks!
Why does style not require the android: prepend?

Comment: *My guess* is that the 'android' prefix is omitted to show that this style is applied only to this button.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the change from `android:theme` to `style` as per the answer provided by Sparta you will want to change

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@drawable/orange_button</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/orange_button</item>
```

Comment: True. It's a residue of experiments I was running to "make it work."